# The number of non-surjective functions between 4-element sets

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Could someone explain to me how I go about answering this question? I know it might be simple, in which case I be quite embarrassed, but I've looked online for the past while and have not found a good tutorial.

Question:

Count the number X of functions

$φ:\{−42,−41,-40,−39\}\to \{15,16,17,18\}$ such that $\phi$ is not onto.

Comment: What do you mean by $(−42,−41,...,−39)$? The set, containing the numbers $-42$, $-41$, $-40$ and $-39$? Also, try to write symbols (numbers, brackets, greek leeter) in [math style](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/). You can improve question and title using [edit].

Comment: It seems a bit goofy to use an ellipsis ("$\ldots$") when there is only a single element being left out of the list, doesn't it? I think it would be better to write $\{-42,-41,-40,-39\}$, and similarly for the range. Note also the use of curly brackets, rather than parentheses, for the set delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have maps between two 4-element sets, you just need to count how many such maps omit at least one value in the range. The actual points in the sets don't matter, as long as you know they both have 4 elements.

It might be easier to first count how many maps of any type there are between the two sets, then count how many of these are onto, then subtract to get your answer.

To count the number of maps of any type, just realize that each domain point can be mapped to any of the 4 range points. So, there are $4\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 4 = 256$ such maps.

The number of onto maps is $4! = 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 24$. This is because the first domain point can be mapped to any of the 4 range points, the second can be mapped to any of the remaining 3 range points, etc.

So, we have computed that there are $4^4-4! = 256-24 = 232$ maps which are not onto.